# Iteration over FileList, React, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm "Reactifying" a file input and can't manage to iterate over selected files.

```js
private onInputChanged = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  let files: FileList | null =  e.currentTarget.files;
  files.map( file => console.log("Do something with " + file.name));
}
```

```html
<input 
    type="file"
    onChange={this.onInputChanged}
/>
```

Here is a barebone example of my problem. FileList cannot be used with .map(... and neither .forEach(...

How can I accomplish an iteration on selected files?

Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FileList'

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) is an Array like object, that has the `length` property, and indexed values, but it lacks the Array methods, such as map. With ES6 you can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert it to a real array. In ES5 you can call [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to convert to an array, or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the method on the FileList.

**Note:** If Array#from causes the *TypeScript | Array.from | error TS2339: Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'* error, change the default **target** (es3) to ES6 - `"target": "ES6"` - in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) of the **"tsconfig.json"**, or use the --target ES6 in the command line.

**Array.from demo:**

```js
const onInputChanged = (e) => {
  const files =  e.currentTarget.files;
  
  Array.from(files).forEach(file => console.log("Do something with " + file.name));
}
```

```html
<input 
    type="file"
    onChange="onInputChanged(event)"
/>
```

**Calling forEach demo:**

```js
const onInputChanged = (e) => {
  const files =  e.currentTarget.files;
  
  [].forEach.call(files, file => console.log("Do something with " + file.name));
}
```

```html
<input 
    type="file"
    onChange="onInputChanged(event)"
/>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, Array.slice() did not work for me, but Array.from() did

Answer (score 2):

The `FileList` interface is accessed using the index:

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i].name);
    //or
    console.log(files.item(i).name);
}
```

You can use either the index with `[0]` or via `item(0)`.

Comment: Is there any reason someone would use `.item(i)`? I realize you've probably just mentioned it for completeness but I figured I would ask.

Comment: Just there for completeness... although I just spotted a typo on the other line, whoops.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate FileList just:

```
for (let file of files) {
    console.log("Do something with " + file.name)
}
```

Comment: This was my first instinct but it throws an error for me - "Error TS2495 (TS) Type 'FileList' is not an array type or a string type."