# Convert file object to array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input form file picker which returns the following object output :

[image]

Image as text ->

```
FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
0: File {name: "Screenshot 2021-02-19 at 12.27.47 PM.png", lastModified: 1613717870763, lastModifiedDate: Fri Feb 19 2021 12:27:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 81142, …}
1: File {name: "Screenshot 2021-02-18 at 12.11.00 PM.png", lastModified: 1613630510734, lastModifiedDate: Thu Feb 18 2021 12:11:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 128961, …}
length: 2
```

I need to convert it to an array of objects of the form :

```
[{file0: file}, {file1: file}]
```

Please note that I don't need the length item present in the initial object in the final array

Comment: Please don't present text as an image.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @trincot I have updated it

Comment: Are you sure that you want a different property name inside each of the objects in the output array? I would hate it if someone fed me that kind of data... I would recommend trying `var arr = Array.from(theFileList)` and see if that works for you.

Comment: @szczocik I tried using iterating for loop in object items and filtering them but seems little bit complicated. Wanted to know if there is any easier solution that I missed out.

Comment: I agree with PeterB: that is a horrible choice for an output format. You don't need those numerical suffixes... you already know the index from the position they have in the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iteration over FileList, React, Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977584/iteration-over-filelist-react-typescript)

Comment: As a comment on: *"I need to convert it to an array of objects"* and *"note that I don't need the length item present in the initial object in the final array"* An array always has a (non-enumerable) `length` property. Which will automatically be set to 2 if you have an array with 2 elements.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an Object {} to an Array \[\] of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const objOfObjs = {
   "one": {"id": 3},
   "two": {"id": 4},
};

const arrayOfObj = Object.entries(objOfObjs).map((e) => ( { [e[0]]: e[1] } ));
```

i think it work for you.

Comment: Altered it to : const res = Object.entries(files).map((e) => ({ [`file${e[0]}`]: e[1] }));

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `Array#map`

```js
const arr = [{name:1},{name:2}];

const res =  arr.map((item,ind)=>({[`file${ind}`]:item}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: A [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) does not have the `map` method. Use `Array.from(fileList).map(...)` instead. Or skip the `map` call, and pass the callback as second argument to [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) eg. `Array.from(fileList, (file, i) => { [\`file${i}\`]: file })`